# How to specify ServiceStack.OrmLite Parameter Length

Tags: parameterized-query, ormlite-servicestack

Using parameterized queries seems to set the length of the parameter to the length of the value passed in.

Doing something like:

```
var person = Connection.Query<People>("select * from People where Name = @name", 
                                      new { name = "Fred"});
```

Causes the parameter to be NVARCHAR(4), so the next query with a different length gets a miss on the cached plans and creates a new one.

How can I change it so it just uses a length I specify.